# Finding the radius of convergence of a cubic Taylor series

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to find the Taylor series and radius of convergence for $x-x^3$ centered at $a = -2$.

I've found the series to be: $$f(x) = 6-11\cdot(x+2)+6\cdot(x+2)^2-(x+2)^3$$

However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to find the radius of convergence for the series.

If it were written as a normal summation, I'd just use the absolute ratio test with $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$, but since I don't have the series in this form I'm not sure what to do. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: All the terms in this series from degree $4$ on have coefficient $0$. It's a finite sum and so converges everywhere. Just think before you jump to formalism and convergence tests...

Comment: @EthanBolker That was my intuition, but you've given me words to describe it. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. You can answer your own question here so it doesn't remain on the unanswered queue.

Comment: A polynomial is its own Taylor series in disguise, whatever the center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_series):

> A series is **convergent** if the sequence of its partial sums
>   $\left \{ S_1,\ S_2,\ S_3,\dots \right \}$ tends to a
>   limit; that means that the partial sums become
>   closer and closer to a given number when the number of their terms
>   increases.

As all the terms in the series greater than degree $4$ have a coefficient of $0$, the partial sums will remain unchanged as the number of terms increases beyond 4. Because of this, the series will converge for all values of $x$.